# Error with tune_bayes() about Gaussian Process being fit on no data

Tags: r, tidymodels

### Description

I am trying to use `tune_bayes()` to optimize two parameters in a decision tree but the function always crashes giving me a an error

```
#> i Gaussian process model
#> ! The Gaussian process model is being fit using 2 features but only has 0
#>   data points to do so. This may cause errors or a poor model fit.
#> ! Gaussian process model: no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf, ...
#> x Gaussian process model: Error in seq_len(n - 1L): argument must be coerc...
#> ! An error occurred when creating candidates parameters:  Error in seq_len(n - 1L) : 
#>   argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
#> Error: `best` should be a single, non-missing numeric
```

With `tune_grid()` the recipes and all work just fine but for some reason `tune_bayes()` does not want to run. I tried to update the tuneable parameters to some other range using `update(...)` but this did not help either. I do not understand why there seems to be no available data.

### Reprex

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

titanic <- read_csv("train.csv")
#> 
#> -- Column specification --------------------------------------------------------
#> cols(
#>   PassengerId = col_double(),
#>   Survived = col_double(),
#>   Pclass = col_double(),
#>   Name = col_character(),
#>   Sex = col_character(),
#>   Age = col_double(),
#>   SibSp = col_double(),
#>   Parch = col_double(),
#>   Ticket = col_character(),
#>   Fare = col_double(),
#>   Cabin = col_character(),
#>   Embarked = col_character()
#> )
titanic <- titanic %>% 
  mutate(
    Survived = factor(
      Survived, 
      levels = c(0, 1), 
      labels = c("Deceased", "Survived")
    )
  )

set.seed(123) 
titanic_split <- initial_split(titanic, strata = Survived)
titanic_train <- training(titanic_split)
titanic_test <- testing(titanic_split)
set.seed(456) 
titanic_folds <- vfold_cv(titanic_train, strata = Survived)

titanic_rec <- recipe(formula = Survived ~ ., data = titanic_train) %>% 
  update_role(PassengerId, new_role = "Id") %>% 
  step_mutate(Cabin = if_else(is.na(Cabin), "Missing", "Available")) %>% 
  step_impute_median(Age) %>% 
  step_mutate(
    title = str_match(Name, ", ([:alpha:]+)\\."),
    title = if_else(is.na(title[, 2]), "NA", title[, 2])
  ) %>% 
  step_other(title, threshold = 0.02, other = "Other") %>% 
  step_rm(Ticket, Embarked) %>% 
  update_role(Name, new_role = "Id") %>% 
  step_string2factor(all_nominal_predictors()) 

titanic_spec <- 
  decision_tree(mode = "classification", tree_depth = tune(), min_n = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("rpart") 

titanic_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(titanic_rec) %>% 
  add_model(titanic_spec)

params <- parameters(titanic_wf) %>% 
  finalize()

options(tidymodels.dark = TRUE)
#doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 6)
set.seed(14834)
titanic_tune <- tune_bayes(
  object = titanic_wf,
  resamples = titanic_folds,
  param_info = params,
  iter = 30,
  initial = 5,
  metrics = metric_set(sensitivity, specificity, mcc, roc_auc),
  control = control_bayes(
    verbose = TRUE, 
    no_improve = 5, 
    save_pred = TRUE, 
    pkgs = "tidyverse"
  )
)
#> 
#> >  Generating a set of 5 initial parameter results
#> v Initialization complete
#> 
#> Optimizing sensitivity using the expected improvement
#> 
#> -- Iteration 1 -----------------------------------------------------------------
#> 
#> i Current best:      sensitivity=NA (@iter NA)
#> i Gaussian process model
#> ! The Gaussian process model is being fit using 2 features but only has 0
#>   data points to do so. This may cause errors or a poor model fit.
#> ! Gaussian process model: no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf, ...
#> x Gaussian process model: Error in seq_len(n - 1L): argument must be coerc...
#> ! An error occurred when creating candidates parameters:  Error in seq_len(n - 1L) : 
#>   argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
#> Error: `best` should be a single, non-missing numeric
#> x Optimization stopped prematurely; returning current results.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  German_Germany.1252         
#>  ctype    German_Germany.1252         
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin               
#>  date     2021-07-05                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package      * version     date       lib source                             
#>  assertthat     0.2.1       2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  backports      1.2.1       2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  broom        * 0.7.6       2021-04-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  cellranger     1.1.0       2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  class          7.3-18      2021-01-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  cli            2.5.0       2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  codetools      0.2-18      2020-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  colorspace     2.0-1       2021-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  crayon         1.4.1       2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  DBI            1.1.0       2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  dbplyr         2.1.1       2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  dials        * 0.0.9       2020-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  DiceDesign     1.9         2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  digest         0.6.27      2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  dplyr        * 1.0.6       2021-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  ellipsis       0.3.2       2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  evaluate       0.14        2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  fansi          0.5.0       2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  fastmap        1.1.0       2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  forcats      * 0.5.1       2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  foreach        1.5.1       2020-10-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  fs             1.5.0       2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  furrr          0.2.2       2021-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  future         1.21.0      2020-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  generics       0.1.0       2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  ggplot2      * 3.3.3       2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  globals        0.14.0      2020-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  glue           1.4.2       2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  gower          0.2.2       2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  GPfit          1.0-8       2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  gtable         0.3.0       2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  hardhat        0.1.5       2020-11-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  haven          2.3.1       2020-06-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  highr          0.9         2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  hms            1.0.0       2021-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  htmltools      0.5.1.9005  2021-07-01 [1] Github (rstudio/htmltools@7fbab16) 
#>  httr           1.4.2       2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  infer        * 0.5.4.9000  2021-03-27 [1] Github (tidymodels/infer@66d24a0)  
#>  ipred          0.9-11      2021-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  iterators      1.0.13      2020-10-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  jsonlite       1.7.2       2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  knitr          1.33        2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  lattice        0.20-41     2020-04-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  lava           1.6.9       2021-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  lhs            1.1.1       2020-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  lifecycle      1.0.0       2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  listenv        0.8.0       2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  lubridate      1.7.10      2021-02-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  magrittr       2.0.1       2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  MASS           7.3-53.1    2021-02-12 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  Matrix         1.3-2       2021-01-06 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  modeldata    * 0.1.0       2020-10-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  modelr         0.1.8       2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  munsell        0.5.0       2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  nnet           7.3-15      2021-01-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  parallelly     1.25.0      2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  parsnip      * 0.1.5.9003  2021-05-22 [1] Github (tidymodels/parsnip@46a2018)
#>  pillar         1.6.1       2021-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  pkgconfig      2.0.3       2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  plyr           1.8.6       2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  pROC           1.17.0.1    2021-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  prodlim        2019.11.13  2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  ps             1.6.0       2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  purrr        * 0.3.4       2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  R6             2.5.0       2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  Rcpp           1.0.6       2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  readr        * 1.4.0       2020-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  readxl         1.3.1       2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  recipes      * 0.1.16.9000 2021-05-29 [1] Github (tidymodels/recipes@0806713)
#>  reprex         2.0.0       2021-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  rlang        * 0.4.11.9000 2021-07-01 [1] Github (r-lib/rlang@dc03e44)       
#>  rmarkdown      2.9.1       2021-07-01 [1] Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@1ea3575) 
#>  rpart        * 4.1-15      2019-04-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  rsample      * 0.1.0       2021-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  rstudioapi     0.13        2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  rvest          1.0.0       2021-03-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  scales       * 1.1.1       2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  sessioninfo    1.1.1       2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  stringi        1.6.2       2021-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  stringr      * 1.4.0       2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  survival       3.2-10      2021-03-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  tibble       * 3.1.2       2021-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  tidymodels   * 0.1.3       2021-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  tidyr        * 1.1.3       2021-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  tidyselect     1.1.1       2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  tidyverse    * 1.3.1       2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  timeDate       3043.102    2018-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  tune         * 0.1.5.9000  2021-05-22 [1] Github (tidymodels/tune@b0e83a7)   
#>  utf8           1.2.1       2021-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  vctrs        * 0.3.8       2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  withr          2.4.2       2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  workflows    * 0.2.2       2021-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)                     
#>  workflowsets * 0.0.2       2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  xfun           0.24        2021-06-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  xml2           1.3.2       2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#>  yaml           2.2.1       2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)                     
#>  yardstick    * 0.0.8       2021-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)                     
#> 
#> [1] C:/Users/Albert/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
#> [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library
```

Answer (score 0):

@AlbertRapp try to upload your packages. It works for current developer versions.